# Exact number of system services

Tags: systemd, init.d

In `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` with `4.4.0-75-generic`

Within `/ect/init.d/`

```
$ ls -1 | wc -l
82
```

On the other hand,

```
$ systemctl list-units | grep service | wc -l
75
```

Why do those two numbers differ? Shouldn't be the same?

Comment: Remove `| wc -l`  and add ` > ~/text1.txt` to the 1st and ` > ~/text2.txt` to the 2nd and you can see the difference with `diff ~/text1.txt ~/text2.txt`.

Comment: The `systemctl list-units` seems to fetch series of units (services) with the pattern  `systemd-*`, e.g. `systemd-journal-flush.service`. These do not seem to have a corresponding script in `/etc/init/d`.